# fso.CopyFile Stopped working in MS Access DB

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10

I have the following code I have been using for a good year now.  I tried to use it today and keep getting permission denied.  I have not changed anything and have been gone for from work for 2w. I have checked everything as well as uninstalled the security fixes from mid December but still doesn't work anymore.  This is a button in my MS Access db that backs up the current DB. I am using MS365.

```
Public Function DBBackup()

Dim fso As FileSystemObject
Dim sSourcePath As String
Dim sSourceFile As String
Dim sBackupPath As String
Dim sBackupFile As String

sSourcePath = "W:\Analysis Check\My Data\"
sSourceFile = "Weekly Chronics DB.accdb"
sBackupPath = "W:\Analysis Check\My Data\"
sBackupFile = "Weekly Chronics DB_" & Format(Date, "mmddyyyy") & ".accdb"

Set fso = New FileSystemObject
fso.CopyFile sSourcePath & sSourceFile, sBackupPath & sBackupFile, True
Set fso = Nothing

Beep
MsgBox "Backup was successful", vbInformation, "Backup Completed"

End Function
```

Comment: "Permission denied" is rather explicit message. Check the permissions on folder. Something must have changed. Is path pointing to location on server?

Comment: Can you manually open the source file from its location and save it to the destination folder with the specified name?  That would be the first thing to try.

Answer (score 0):

Check to be sure the source file is not locked
another possible cause is
destination folder having permission issue.